Assertion error thrown when code converted from Scenario to Scenario Outline
Issue: Scenario Outline parameterization
Tech:  python, behave
I run the test changing the username (in the feature file) to “”,   or “username” , none of them made a difference. It just throws the below assertion errorThe step definition class passes that parameter to the method name step_defn():
Also tweak the parameter like “{input}” or {input}
Note: this below code works perfect with Scenario. The issues has to do with Scenario Outline.
Feature:

Scenario Outline:
    Given I log into the chrome page
    When I enter “<username>” in the text field

Examples:
|useparam|
|USERNAME|   => This value is constant in case it matters to the step definition class


Steps: 
@then(u’I enter {input} in the text field’)    Note: behave changed When to @then 
Def step-defn(context, input):
    data_passed = get_property_name(context.testimony, ‘witness’)

    input_constant = None
    for x, y in context.values_map.items():
    if y == data_passed:
        input_constant = x
        break

#verification
    assert input_constant = input

Once you run the above code (in behave), you get these below assertion error messages

          … assert input_constant == input

    AssertionError

If you debug, you see these issues: 
    input = {str} ‘ “USERNAME” ‘   
    input_constant = {str} ‘USERNAME’ 

Changed the parameter in the feature file to “”,   or “username” against the step definition class passing the {param} or "{param}" or '{param}'
